# why is the critically damped response faster than the under damped response?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on a project and am finding struggle in knowing the answer of a question ,,

why is the critically damped response of the 2nd order system faster than the under damped response??

any help???

Comment: What exactly does faster mean? Faster in responding to what kind of disturbance?

Comment: what I mean is that the response of the system gets faster and by that u can say that the time constant decreases,,,so it gets faster responding to the decrease os the time constant

Comment: Can you define what you mean by the time constant?

Comment: its is the time required for the system to decay to zero

Comment: That's...not a normal use of the term, please explain further. Ordinarily it is the "1/e time", similar to the half-life but with 1/2 replaced by 1/e.

Comment: exactly,,,but that not my question am looking for an answer to the question above